# Siilverlight EventTrigger Button.Click throws Error

Tags: silverlight, events, button, triggers, click

I've got this Code in Silverlight 4:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Height="25" Width="25">
                <Button.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="200" Duration="00:00:00.5" Storyboard.TargetName="BigMenu" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Button.Triggers>
                <Image Source="../ResX/expand.png"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Height="25" Width="25">
                <Image Source="../ResX/pin.png"/>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Height="25" Width="25" Margin="0,10,0,5" Click="bSelf_Click">
                <Image Source="../ResX/selfass.png"/>
                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip Content="Selbsteinschätzung" />
                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            </Button>
            <Button Height="25" Width="25" Margin="0,5,0,5" Click="bforeign_Click">
                <Image Source="../ResX/extass.png"/>
                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip Content="Fremdeinschätzung"/>
                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            </Button>
            <Button Height="25" Width="25" Margin="0,5,0,5" Click="bSearch_Click">
                <Image Source="../ResX/search.png"/>
                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip Content="Suche" />
                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            </Button>
            <Button Height="25" Width="25" Margin="0,5,0,10" Click="bAdministration_Click">
                <Image Source="../ResX/admin.png"/>
                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip Content="Administration"/>
                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="BigMenu">
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
```

So on Initializing i've got this Error thrown:

```
XAMLParseException occured. Fehler beim Zuweisen zu Eigenschaft
'System.Windows.EventTrigger.RoutedEvent'. [Line: 22 Position: 47]
```

Which is this:

```
   <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
```

I ain't see any Error on this Code.
I Would appriciate any help.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MSDN documentation for EventTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb979699(v=vs.95).aspx):

> In Silverlight, the only event that you can use for an EventTrigger is the Loaded event.

The error is because you're using an event other than Loaded (i.e. `Button.Click`) with an EventTrigger.